# Custom hover tags like Thinglink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a way to simulate what Thinglink does.

I attach a picture so you can understand it better.
Essentially, its a dot in the picture, and when you hover it with mouse, it will display a text box.

My ideas to begin are, tooltip within bootstrap, but doesn't know for sure if you can make it on a picture...

[image: Thinglink picture]

EDIT:

Add my actual code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 column wow fadeInRight delay=1000ms">
    <div id="tooltip1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="keyword1">
        <div id="tooltip2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="keyword2">
            <div id="tooltip3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="keyword3">
                <img src="img/IPHONE_SCREENSHOT.png" alt="iOS" />
            </div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks to @Wouter Florijn
I added bootstrap tooltip and a transparent img 16x16, beacuase its needed to tooltip to work. (Can't hover in an empty zone...)

```
<img src="img/IPHONE_SCREENSHOT.png" alt="iOS" />
<div class="dot" data-x="20%" data-y="25%"><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Feature 1"><img src="img/dot_transparent.png"/></a></div>
<div class="dot" data-x="80%" data-y="50%"><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Feature 2"><img src="img/dot_transparent.png" /></a></div>
<div class="dot" data-x="35%" data-y="80%"><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Feature 3"><img src="img/dot_transparent.png" /></a></div>
<div class="dot" data-x="55%" data-y="15%"><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Feature 4"><img src="img/dot_transparent.png" /></a></div>
```

Comment: So... What have you tried? And if you say *"Nothing"*, that's probably where you should start.

Comment: Im trying to get it done with popover, but i dont find to get it ON my image

Comment: So post the code you've tried and we'll help you debug it. SO is not a free coding service. We aren't going to code this for you.

Comment: @TimLewis there you have my actual code, it works, but I want to specify the exact position of the tooltip and a dot or something that tells the user there is a tooltip there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a container div for the picture and then add a number of absolutely positioned divs inside the container.

It would be best to position the dots using JS I think.

Then, add tooltips to the `.dot` divs using whatever you want. jQuery UI, Bootstrap, Foundation... Or your own code of course.

**https://jsfiddle.net/7whLrjry/1/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="..." />
    <div class="dot" data-x="20%" data-y="25%"></div>
    <div class="dot" data-x="80%" data-y="50%"></div>
    <div class="dot" data-x="35%" data-y="80%"></div>
    <div class="dot" data-x="55%" data-y="15%"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 8px solid white;
    border-radius: 99999px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dot:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 8px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dot').each(function() {
        $(this).css('left', $(this).data('x'));
        $(this).css('top', $(this).data('y'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Great!! Will adapt it know to implement tooltips and will come back!